# How to delete desktop theme in oracle apex for a mobile application

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

In oracle apex 18.1, by default when we create a new application - we are provided with Desktop user interface and in order to create a mobile application , we need to create a new theme from the repository using mobile interface.
But how can we delete this Desktop user interface and keep only the mobile interface? What's the significance of desktop user interface in mobile oracle apex?

Answer (score 1):

The mobile theme is deprecated from 18.x, so you only have one user interface to choose from.

https://joelkallman.blogspot.com/2017/08/an-important-change-is-coming-for.html

The Universal Theme is absorbing mobile templates and dynamic actions, and newer ones are being added each version.